# Getting DataType error when trying to sync Node server (Express) with Postgres backend (Sequelize)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Im trying to get my server up and running and connected to my postgres db but I keep getting this error:

```
rs/Desktop/Jobletics/models/employer.js:7
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'STRING' of undefined
```

Here is the code in gist:

https://gist.github.com/rahul1346/cb8e93796c8af9ebd77e

What am I passing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

DataTypes is undefined. It doesn't exist. Go back through your code to where it came from and find out why.

Comment: I get a blank screen when I go to your link to look at the code. Also, you might have defined DataTypes, but value was ever assigned to it, or the value was removed.

Comment: Thank you.

https://gist.github.com/rahul1346/cb8e93796c8af9ebd77e

That is the gist...it should work. Where do you generally assign the value? Isnt it supposed to be passed thru when the route is called?

Comment: Okay, was able to get in. Not a sequelize expert, we only used it for a little while, and then switched to using Mongo. Looking at the docs for sequelize, it looks like it's just a convenience class, but they are not clear about where it comes from. It also states that you can probably just use 'STRING'. http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/datatypes/index.html?highlight=DataTypes. Looking at these docs, it's almost as though it can only be used when defining the model itself.

Comment: Interesting. Thinking of just doing this in Mongo myself. But this app im trying to build will have many relational dependencies.